# Duda con if else

Tags: javascript, condiciones, else

estoy tratando de hacer el Tic-Tac-Toe y estaba programando la parte de los turnos. Tenia la cabeza quemada y no sabia como hacerlo hasta que logre mi cometido. Aqui el código :

```
function Player(name, boolean, chip, color) {
this.name = name;
this.turn = boolean;
this.chip = chip;
this.color = color;

this.addChip = function (array) {
    array.forEach(celda => {
        celda.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (this.turn) {

                celda.innerHTML = this.chip;
                celda.style.background = this.color;
                this.turn = false;
                console.log(this.turn, this.name);
            } else {
                this.turn = true;
            }
        }, { once: true });
    });
}
```

}

Lo que quería saber es si esto es correcto: cuando se escucha el evento click, se verifica el turno del usuario, si este es verdadero ejecuta la función, pero si es falso, "setea" el turno del jugador a true y vuelve a preguntar si es verdadero y ejecuta la función? No tengo mucha idea de programación y se me esta por explotar la cabeza jajaja

Estos son los objetos instanciados:

```
//Creando los jugadores
const fichas = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');

const player1 = new Player($('#player1').val(), true, 'X', 'red');
const player2 = new Player($('#player2').val(), false, 'O', "green");

player1.addChip(fichas);
player2.addChip(fichas);
```

Comment: Y lo probaste? funciona? hace algo mal?

Comment: funciona, lo que queria saber es si esto tiene sentido: cuando se escucha el evento click, se verifica el turno del usuario, si este es verdadero ejecuta la función, pero si es falso, "setea" el turno del jugador a true y vuelve a preguntar si es verdadero y ejecuta la función?

Comment: No, la función solo se va a ejecutar cuando hagas click

Comment: Y... no tendrias que verificar si el otro jugador jugo, antes de devolverle el turno?

Comment: se tiene que ejecutar la funcion al hacer click. SI nesecitar mas ayuda con el  Tic-Tac-Toe. estaré feliz de responderte